# Merge multiple rows in SQL with tie breaking on primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, duplicates

I have a table with data like the following

```
key | A | B    | C
---------------------------
 1  | x | 0    | 1
 2  | x | 2    | 0
 3  | x | NULL | 4
 4  | y | 7    | 1
 5  | y | 3    | NULL
 6  | z | NULL | 4
```

And I want to merge the rows together based on column A with largest primary key being the 'tie breaker' between values that are not NULL

```
Result
key | A | B    | C
---------------------------
 1  | x | 2    | 4
 2  | y | 3    | 1
 3  | z | NULL | 4
```

What would be the best way to achieve this assuming my data is actually 40 columns and 1 million rows with an unknown level of duplications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` and conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71f4d/1/0)

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rnB = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY CASE WHEN B IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, [key] DESC),
        rnC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY CASE WHEN C IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, [key] DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    [key] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A),
    A,
    B = MAX(CASE WHEN rnB = 1 THEN B END),
    C = MAX(CASE WHEN rnC = 1 THEN C END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY A
```

Comment: as a small extension to this, how would it work if A was instead 2 columns (Firstname, Lastname)?

Comment: Just replace any occurrence of `A` with `FirstName,LastName`

Comment: I just came across another minor issue with this. I'm hoping to preserve the largest [key] value associated with each record. (x=3, y=5, z=6). I attempted to try [key] = MAX([key]) OVER(PARTITION BY concat(First, Last)), but that's giving me errors